# virtualenvwrapper import old vitualenvs

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

After using `virtualenv` for some time I just discovered the wonders of `virtualenvwrapper`. However, is there any way of importing my old virtualenvs so that `virtualenvwrapper` will recognize them?

To clarify, say that before I installed `virtualenvwrapper`, I had an old virtualenv located in `~/virtualenvs/myoldenv`, now when I have `virtualenvwrapper` installed is there a way to tell it about `myoldenv` I can simply type `workon myoldenv` in the future without `mkvirtualenv`-ing it from scratch

## —Update

This is how I handled it, but I don't know if there is a better approach

```
$ mkvirtualenv myoldenv
$ cp -r ~/oldvirtualenvs/myoldenv ~/Envs
$ workon myoldenv
(myoldenv)$ lssitepackages
#> outputs my old sitepackages
```

where `~/Envs` is my `$WORKON_HOME`

Comment: I'm assuming that `~/Envs` is your `$WORKON_HOME`? That's probably how I would have done it.

Comment: Yes, `~/Envs` is my `$WORKON_HOME`

Comment: So what James is suggesting is why not just `export WORKON_HOME=~/oldvirtualenvs/`?